# Issue running Next.js on iisnode on Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, express, iisnode, next.js

Trying to deploy and run Next.js on Azure Web App. Azure Web App works when running just with Express.js but as soon as I call `nex()` it fails. Tried to enable the error logging in Azure portal but not much of any use came out, just generic 500 errors.

Below is what works and what doesn't.

Works:

```
var express = require('express');
var expressServer = express();

expressServer.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Express is working on IISNode!');
});

expressServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Does not work:

```
var express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
var expressServer = express();
var app = next();

expressServer.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Express is working on IISNode!');
});

expressServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

I don't even bother getting request handler at this point as the `app = next()` is failing.

Package.json:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "9.4.0 || 8.9.x"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",   
    "next": "^4.2.3",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^1.3.5",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.11"
  }
```

**EDIT:**
I believe the issue is that `next build` needs to run first. I am looking if I can add some post deployment/build command with something like Kudu. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Try adding `"prestart": "next build"` to your `package.json` scripts.

Comment: Hi @RVid did you manage to make next.js deployment to azure web app to work?

Comment: @Bida yes, next.js works fine on Azure Web App. You also need your web.config file if you are running on Windows instance. It might be better to create a new question with more details of your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you need to run `next build` first.

So, this would work in Azure Web App if you create `pages` directory under project root and edit the `package.json` to add this:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "next build"
}
```

Comment: I still get error 500 even if i apply this fix, do you maybe have some other tips? :)